# Elements in an Array symmetric

Tags: java, arrays, reverse, element

This is my code:

```
if (refractedAngleInDegrees > 60.0)
{
    System.out.println ("The angle is making a reflection");

    //should reverse the array and make it into a palindrome-like array
    for (int f = 0; f < gradient.length /2; f++)
    {
        double anglesReversed = angleArray[f];
        angleArray[f] = angleArray[gradient.length - f - 1];
        angleArray[gradient.length - f - 1] = anglesReversed;

    }
    for (int e = 0; e < gradient.length; e++)

    {
        //System.out.println(angleArray[e]);
    }

}
else
{
    System.out.println ("The angle is refracting");
}
System.out.println(angleArray[x]);
x++;
}
```

So I am stuck for my program. When it hits 60, I want it to reverse the values.

For instance, if I have an array of [1 2 3 4 5], and it keeps going until it hits 5.

I want it to go backwards and do [ 1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1] (or until the array slots end), but I think I just ended up reversing the values...

Also, I would like the else statement to stop after the angle "makes a reflection". Would I put a break there?

This is the code before this, which might be the reason why it's wrong because it keeps printing out NaN after the angle hits the reflection. Reflection equals to 0, which is also wrong...

```
double incidentAngleInDegrees = 10.0;
double incidentAngleInRadian;
double refractedAngleInDegrees;
double refractedAngleInRadian;
double storedAngleInDegrees;
double storedAngleInRadian;
int x = 0;


//loop for refraction
double[] angleArray = new double [gradient.length];
while(x < 120)

{
    incidentAngleInRadian = incidentAngleInDegrees * (Math.PI / 180);  // converting incident angle from degrees to radians


    refractedAngleInRadian = Math.asin((indexArray[x] * incidentAngleInRadian) / indexArray[x + 1]); //getting the refracted angle in radians

    refractedAngleInDegrees = refractedAngleInRadian * (180 / Math.PI);

    storedAngleInDegrees = refractedAngleInDegrees;  // storing refracted angle in degrees

    incidentAngleInDegrees = storedAngleInDegrees;  // making the refracted angle in degree into the new incident angle in degrees

    angleArray[x] = storedAngleInDegrees;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reflect the whole array, here's the code for it:

```
class Rev {
static int[] reflected(int[] a) {
    int[] b = new int[a.length<<1];
    System.arraycopy(a, 0, b, 0, a.length);
    int i, j;
    for (j = a.length-1, i = 0; j>=0; j--, i++) {
        b[a.length+i] = a[j];
    }
    return b;
}

static void printArray(int[] a) {
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(a[i] + ",");
    }
    System.out.println();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int[] a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int[] b = reflected(a);
    printArray(a);
    printArray(b);
}
}
```

If you want to reflect a part of it, you just need to modify this code slightly. Hope this helps.

The output is:

```
1,2,3,4,5,
1,2,3,4,5,5,4,3,2,1,
```